# How to connect Power BI to IBM DB2

Tags: db2, powerbi, dashdb, powerbi-datasource

Currently, I am trying to query data from IBM DB2 and then present it in Power BI. However, I notice the information that Power BI needs is different from what I got from the IBM DB2.

The information that Power BI needs is:

[image: Power BI interface]

The connection information of IBM DB2 is shown as below:

```
Host name:  dashdb-enterprisex-xx-xxxx-01.services.xxx.bluemix.net
Port number:    50001
Database name:  BLUDB
User ID:    userid
Password:   ********
```

What should I fill in?

Answer (score 1):

Server Name is Host Name:Port Number, in your case:

```
dashdb-enterprisex-xx-xxxx-01.services.xxx.bluemix.net:50001
```

Database name is: BLUDB

Beware, there might be issues with the IBM driver, and you will need to do additional research.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Microsoft driver. It worked for me.

For server name, you should enter - *dashdb-enterprisex-xx-xxxx-01.services.xxx.bluemix.net:*
For database name, enter - *BLUDB*
Then, click **OK**.

It will take you to next page. There are 2 tabs on that page Windows and Database.
Choose Database and enter your username and password.

Below that, there'll be a dropdown to apply settings at level - here, choose server name + database.